# Ocultar registro para o usuário

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Ao "excluir" um registro preciso oculta-lo de uma tabela, na exibição do usuário, mas ele deve permanecer no banco.
Eu coloquei um campo chamado '`status`' na tabela que gerencia justamente isso.
Na exibição eu coloquei um '`if`' que realiza o filtro no momento do 'select'. Mostrando apenas os registros com o '`status == 1`'.

Até ai está tudo bem, meu problema é dar o '`update`' para trocar apenas o valor do '`status`' de 1 para 0. No momento que o usuário decidir excluir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o seu caso for somente para atualizar no banco esse exemplo resolve:

```
UPDATE COMPANY SET ADDRESS = 'Texas' WHERE ID = 6;

UPDATE sua_tabela SET seu_campo = valor_para_alterar WHERE ID = id_que_sera_atualizado;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao tentar Excluir verifique o status do registro, e se for 1 atualiza para 0 e passa o ponteiro do banco para o próximo registro.